# Wso2 api manager endpoint validation

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I managed to deploy wso2 api manager in aks , but when i try to create an api and validate the endpoint , it shows connection error , validation works fine when i run wso2 api manager on my local.
One more thing the endpoint i try to use is deployed in another vm  and requires a vpn connection , i thought it might be the problem , is there anyway to connect to this endpoint from my cluster ?
[image]

and this is the log of the error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the browser does the HTTP HEAD request to the backend. I think from your machine it cannot connect to the backend.

You can skip this step and deploy the API to the Gateway. So in that case you can configure the gateway to connect via the proxy to your backend service.

Apply the following config in the deployment.toml file in conf directory.

```
[[transport.http.proxy_profile]]
target_hosts = ["www.mocky.io"]
proxy_host = "localhost"
proxy_port = "8080"
```

Refer [1] for more information on configurations. This blog[2] has some details about the proxy behavior.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/advance-configurations/changing-the-default-transport/#transport-sender-parameters

[2] - https://medium.com/@dushaniw/setting-up-a-proxy-between-wso2-apim-and-backend-535dd0789c14

Comment: what www.mocky.io would represent in my case ??

Comment: Your backend endpoint.